# Is there an equivalent bitwise operator to +=?

Tags: c

I was just wondering if there was something like += but with bitwise instead this is just out of curiosity because I have a project like that coming up soon

like what would this be

```
a += b
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "bitwise"?

Comment: All binary operators can be combined with `=`. `a op= b` is equivalent to `a = a op b`

Comment: So if there's a bitwise operator that does what you want, put it before `=` to do that.

Comment: All of C's binary operators that I can think of have equivalent assignment operators.

Comment: The 1-bit addition table is the same as [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_XOR_^).

Comment: @matt I'm kinda new to C but if someone were to ask you to replace that operation with a bitwise operation what would that mean? or is more context needed for this question?

Comment: To be clear, have you been asked to implement operator `+=` using only bitwise operators?

Comment: if somebody were to ask me to replace that operation with a bitwise operation my response would be, "what do you mean?" which is exactly what we are asking you

Comment: @Bob__ yes that's what is being asked

Comment: By "operation" are you sure you aren't being asked to create a routine to do binary addition and not just bit-wise addition?

Comment: @Rob wait i think you're right lol thank you sorry for this dumb question 

Comment: @luther well your thinking excludes such operators as `&&`, `||` or the two-placed `x[y]` for example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to add using only the bitwise logical operators:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int addb(int a, int b)
{
    while (b)
    {
        int c = a & b;
        a = a ^ b; 
        b = c << 1;
    }
    return a;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", addb(5,8));
    printf("%d\n", addb(5,-2));
}
```